# ASP.NET: где изначально устанавливается свойство HttpContext.User?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

HttpContext имеет свойство User типа IPrincipal.

Во всей документации, которую я прочитал, сказано, что это свойство может быть установлено модулями, такими как **WindowsAuthenticationModule** или **FormsAuthenticationModule**. Но если взглянуть в их исходный код, то можно увидеть, что не все так просто.

К примеру  **WindowsAuthenticationModule** перед тем как начать выполнять свою логику пытается сослаться на это свойство для текущего контекста:

```
  WindowsPrincipal user = context.User as WindowsPrincipal;
            if (user != null) {/* code... */}
```

Причем невыполнение этого условия (то есть если наше свойство равно null или оно не относится к типу WindowsPrincipal) в интегрированном режиме IIS приведет к тому, что модуль просто не будет продолжать свою работу.
Вопросы у меня такие:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что IIS, который в любом случае должен
   передать нашему приложению метку о пользователе Windows, от имени
   которого выполняется запрос (в зависимости от конфигурации IIS:
   аутентифицированный юзер или анонимный), и есть поставщик того
   объекта, который в ASP.NET будет завернут в **WindowsIdentity** и
   **WindowsPrincipal** (причем обязательно в объекты этого типа)?
2. Если верно 1, то где происходит первоначальная установка **HttpContext.User**?
3. Если верно 1, то при каких обстоятельствах **HttpContext.User**  будет равно null? У меня единственное соображение, такое возможно, когда мы в Web.config поставили:

   < authentication mode="None" />

Тогда нашему приложению "неинтересен"идентификатор от IIS. Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно легко посмотреть на практике - снять Debug/Options/Enable Just my code и поставить брекпойнт на конструктор соответствующего Identity:

Debug/New Breakpoint/Break at function -> `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal..ctor(System.Security.Principal.Identity)`

Стектрейс на моей машине:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ntIdentity)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetUserPrincipal()  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SynchronizeVariables(System.Web.HttpContext context)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[AppDomain Transition]
```

Соответствующая cтрочка в reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/IIS7WorkerRequest.cs,2253